# How to filter a select box based on a typeahead selection

Tags: angularjs

When I create a new Job I select a Customer and Customer Employees based on a property "CustomerEmployeeRole". I select a Customer from a typeahead input. I need that selection to filter 2 select boxes with the Customer Employees that have the same CustomerId as the selected Customer. I have created a plunkr. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r4K2Wh9NBwpCQCQlvbPq?p=preview)

```
<label>Customer:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="currentItem.CustomerName"
  typeahead="customer.CustomerName for customer in customerArray | filter:$viewValue"
  typeahead-on-select="selectCustomer($item)">

 <label>CustomerPM:</label>
 <select ng-options="customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' +    customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName as customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' +  customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName for customer in customerEmployeeArray | filter: {CustomerEmployeeRole : 'PM'}" ng-model="currentItem.CustomerEmployeeId"> 
 <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
 </select>

 <label>CustomerSuper:</label>
 <select ng-options="customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' + customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName as customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' + customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName for customer in customerEmployeeArray | filter:{CustomerEmployeeRole : 'Super'} " ng-model="currentItem.CustomerEmployeeId">
 <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
<select ng-options="customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' + customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName as customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' + customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName for customer in customerEmployeeArray | filter:{CustomerEmployeeRole : 'Super', CustomerId : currentItem.CustomerId} " ng-model="currentItem.CustomerEmployeeId">
```

I mean you need the next filter:

```
filter:{CustomerEmployeeRole : 'Super', CustomerId : currentItem.CustomerId}
```

So now you will see just those `Customer Employees` which have role `Super` and `id` as on the selected from `typeahead` `currentItem.CustomerId`.

#### Changed plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/r0Y2b8WvUNjyg5fKLDsL?p=preview

P.S. I think you have wrong models for your `CustomerPM` and `CustomerSuper`: the are the same,so when you choose PM - Super has the same value and in the selectbox it becomes `Select`. Choose different models for these two `select`'s and all will be working fine.